# Converting NAs does not work in R

Tags: r, missing-data, na

I have a data frame, df, and a factor class vector, "EMAIL_STATUS". if I do:

```
table(df$EMAIL_STATUS, useNA="always")
```

I get `38716 <NA>`, `638 "YES"`, `110 "9999"`.

I want to convert the 38716 s to "UNKNOWN". I try the following code:

```
df$EMAIL_STATUS[is.na(df$EMAIL_STATUS)] <- "UNKNOWN"
```

I get no error, but it does not convert the NAs to "UNKNOWN", in fact it does nothing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you provide a reproducible example the illustrates it?

Comment: It is challenging to reproduce, because normally this code works ... when I create a dataframe from scratch this code works. I am looking for someone who might be able to determine why, for some reason this is not working...

It is in  my opinion, like how 1 + 1 = 2, and then all of a sudden I do 1 + 1 and get 9....

Comment: So...you're looking for someone with mind reading powers or simply a good guesser? ;) Look, if you haven't narrowed it down to something reproducible you probably aren't ready to ask for help here yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This short example illustrates one of possible ways of introducing a new *level* into a factor:

```
x <- factor(c(NA, NA, "a", "b", NA, "b"))
x[is.na(x)] <- "c" # this won't work, no such level as "c" in levels(x)
## Warning message:
## In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(x), value = "c") :
##   invalid factor level, NA generated
levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "c") #include a new category
x[is.na(x)] <- "c"
x
## [1] c c a b c b
```

Comment: That would be my guess too.

Comment: Amazing- thank you for explaining this. Didn't realize R wasn't dynamic in this way...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without example data
but try this

```
df$EMAIL_STATUS <- as.character(df$EMAIL_STATUS)   
df[ df$EMAIL_STATUS %in% NA, "EMAIL_STATUS" ] <- "UNKNOWN"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work I get the following error:
Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD %in% NA, "PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD",  : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD %in% NA, "PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: ok, do this first:  df$EMAIL_STATUS <- as.character(df$EMAIL_STATUS)